# How do I uninstall "Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 RC2 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 1"?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

I'm having trouble uninstalling `Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 RC2 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 1`.  I'm in Windows 7, in the `Programs and Features` window.  When I click `uninstall`, it brings up a dialog box, with the options `repair`, `uninstall`, and `cancel`.  When I click `uninstall`, a "Open file" window pops up.

I've googled a bit to see if there's a file I can download to sate this "Open file" window.  I can't find one anywhere.  Here are a few of the things I have looked at, but I can't make sense of which one may fit.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download

The reason I'm trying to uninstall this is because I'm having a lot of trouble with Visual Studio 2015 community, and this is part of the troubleshooting process.

Comment: This is a really stupid problem that MS failed to take into account. It's like not a single person at MS actually USES their damn software. I'm glad you made this post.

Comment: See also https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/876

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Download a copy of the installer exe from Microsoft:

- [DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1.exe](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/6/1/46116DFF-29F9-4FF8-94BF-F9BE05BE263B/DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1.exe)
- [DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/3/8/A38489F3-9777-41DD-83F8-2CBDFAB2520C/DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe)
- [DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.1.exe](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=824849)
- [DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.2.exe](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/5/7/557D02A5-C3D0-4EF6-A570-4F75CD0DA5BF/DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.2.exe)
- [DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe](https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/E/F6ECBBCC-B02F-424E-8E03-D47E9FA631B7/DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe)
- [DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.4.exe](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release/VS2015Tools/DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.4.exe)

After choose this file when asked. Then you can successfully remove it.

Comment: Thank you, but how did you know to go there?

Comment: I have simmiliar problem but I need AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909.exe

Can't find it anywhere online. 
Anybody have it?

Comment: @hex Here's the [link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/8/0/18048EDD-9F45-479A-B208-6F7C91CF2ECC/AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909.exe) (via [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1449#issuecomment-219578445)).

Comment: Not sure about the version in my case, uninstall is looking for "DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.1.exe"

Comment: Using the 2.1 link did get the uninstall going but i ended up with a "the specified account already exists" error. Any tips for that?

Comment: @Entrodus I had this message too. Just reboot your machine

Comment: Do you have a link for 2.0.3 ?
Nevermind found it https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827524

Comment: @SaintGerbil Did that link work for you as I couldn't get it to uninstall using that link.

Comment: It did but it looks like it redirects back to Preview 2 now.... :-(
I'll have a dig and update the link

Comment: Thank you. I could not find any old versions on the MS site.

Comment: as of today the links are 404 dead.

Comment: I found a working link for DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2:
https://github.com/Ruikuan/Img/blob/master/DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe

Comment: Does anyone have a link for DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1.exe? The Microsoft download link for that one is also dead

Comment: I've just downloaded the installer for "DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.4.exe" posted by this answer and successfully uninstalled the tool. I'm sharing this because someone commented the links were down.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I also had to manually start the .exe as Administrator, otherwise uninstall completes, but does not actually remove .NET Core installation.

Answer (score 0):

I hit a roadblock uninstalling **Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 RC2 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 1** as well. This is still an ongoing problem in *2020* as I am using *Windows 10* *:)*. *Note* that the *original* question by [@r12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726336/r12) above was targeting *Windows 7*. However, I believe the **Alternative Solution** which I am providing in this response, is still an *applicable solution model*, to work with *older* versions of *Windows* as well.

When I visited the **`Programs and Features`** *settings window* and **`Clicked`** on **`Uninstall`**; I was experiencing the same **`'Open file'`** *dialog*, which [@r12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726336/r12) was experiencing. However again, I had the issue on *Windows 10*, whereas [@r12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726336/r12) was using *Windows 7*. This lead me to *believe* it was a *logic bug* in the *Uninstaller application* specifically.

In addition, I encountered an annoyance after each *failed uninstall attempt*; where I could **not** *perform* a **second** *uninstall attempt*, without **first** *rebooting*. The *rebooting* between *failed uninstall attempts* was necessary, as the **`Programs and Features`** *titled*, *informational* **`wait dialog`**,  with the **`label`** *'Please wait until the current program is finished uninstalling or being changed.'*, would *appear* for all *subsequent* **`Uninstall`** *option* **`Clicks`**. I waited beyond *10 minutes* initially, on a *Core i3*. I gave up waiting and *rebooted*, instead of *'waiting it out'*, on what I *presumed* was a *hanging state* type of **logic error** in the *Uninstaller application*, that would **never** finish.

My *assumption* for why the *Uninstall process* is *'erring out early'*, is due to the **`'Open file'`** *dialog* calling code in the *Uninstall process* is being returned an **unexpected value**, and is mishandling the result when **no valid** **`exe file`** is selected by the user in the **`'Open file'`** *dialog*. The process is then *'erring out early'* and *bypassing* the code that would notify *Windows* that the *Uninstall process* has been *completed as cancelled* by the *user*.

I also *believe* that having to select an **`exe file`** at all, during the *Uninstall process*, was never the **`intent`** for a *normal end-user use-case*, by the *uninstaller application development team*. This is **significant** in that, it further reveals a more *complicated issue* of having to do with the potential for it being related to **`IIS permissions`** or **`IIS file locking`** of the *existing* **`exe file`** or *Uninstall/Install/Runner service*.

I am thinking that **`IIS`** is potentially using the **`exe file`** or *service/windows service* as an operational resource, which should be more *decoupled* in nature; however, that this is interfering with the *Uninstall* portion of the *service life-cycle*. It appears that the default action of the *Uninstall process*, when encountering *file-system* related issues, could be to simply offer an **`'Open file'`** *dialog* to the user. The *purpose* being, so the *Uninstall developers* and *Uninstall testers* of this  *service/windows service*, can simply select a *test exe file*; which doesn't fully uninstall the service for speed in *repeat test-ability*.

I had also attempted to *restart Windows* prior to returning to the **`Programs and Features`** window again, however encountered *repeat results*. Some of you may be thinking of *Albert Einstein* stating *'The definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results'*, as humor here in this cyclical reboot context. However, I hope you reconsider the fact I was already in the midst of uninstalling many *applications* and *framework tools* **initially**, **prior** to running into this *problem*, and simply had **not** *rebooted* yet *:)*. When hitting *application errors* with any version of *Windows*, *rebooting* can be your **first** *best option* to a *resolution*. Although, I will say I was perhaps a bit zealous to even attempt an *uninstall* the **third** and **fourth** times after *reboots*, but lets just pretend I did not have *high* hopes.

I did find a separate **Alternative Solution** which did not require me to download any copies of the *installer* **`exe files`**, which had been *linked* in the *previous solution* answered by [@Vincent Liou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6422822/vincent-liou). For my specific example here, I assume I would have only needed to download the single **`exe file`** from *Microsoft*: [DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1.exe](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/6/1/46116DFF-29F9-4FF8-94BF-F9BE05BE263B/DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1.exe), and then provide this to the *Uninstaller application* when prompted.

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:**
What I had done to to work around or fix the **logic error** in the *already installed, uninstaller application/service*, was to instead use the following *instructions*:

- **`Visit`** the **`Programs and Features`** window.
- **`Click`** on the link option **`Turn Windows features on or off`**.
- **`Disable`** checkbox **`.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)`**.
- **`Disable`** checkbox **`.NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services`**.
- **`Disable`** checkbox **`Internet Information Services`**.
- **`Reboot`**.
- **`Visit`** the **`Programs and Features`** window.
- **`Select`** program **`Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 RC2 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 1`**.
- **`Click`** on the **`Uninstall`** link.

I was able to get the **Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 RC2 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview** service uninstalled correctly with this solution. I do not know if anything more than only **IIS** being *disabled* alone, was needed here. I was in the process of cleaning up, and uninstalling three older, *Visual Studio software IDE's*, and attempting to upgrade my Dev Box to a more current day, *VS 2019* and *.NET Core environment*; which is why I thought to **`Disable`** checkbox **`.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)`** and **`.NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services`**. However, I do not know if this *action* was in fact, *part of the solution*. I also have no more time to dedicate to this.

Good luck and the Einstein quote was seen: professorbuzzkill.com/einstein-insanity-qnq and I also just linked this to a # hashtag, instead of the real link; because, I do not know if it is a safe link. Just search for it if you are unfamiliar, and are looking for the original source.

Comment: Doesn't work as stated at least. I have `Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 RC2 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 1`, and having follow the steps exactly I still get a dialog for `DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1`.