# Uninstall .Net Core SDK when Visual Studio no longer exists

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I started cleaning up VS 2015 & in the process I ended up uninstalling all toolings.

Now stuck up with this issue:
[How do I uninstall "Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 RC2 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 1"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624775/how-do-i-uninstall-microsoft-net-core-1-0-0-rc2-vs-2015-tooling-preview-1)

Solution provided is to download original installer. Unfortunately that gives that Visual studio 2015 does not exist on the system.

> Am I locked- up with this tooling?
>   Where does the installed SDK resides so that at least I can delete the
>   folder physically?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The EXE requires VS or VWD to be installed because some of the installers (MSIs) make configuration changes to VS.

If you removed VS already, you will need to manually uninstall the MSIs. The EXE installer in the dialog you posted has a log file. Can you look at the log and tell me the version of the installer.

Then I can track down the items you need to manually remove and I can update my answer.

There are a number of VS tooling MSIs and some .NET Core items that need to be removed. Depending on the version you have, an installation of NuGet for VS2015, ASP.NET Core Module for IIS/IISExpress and Azure App Services could be part of this.

Jacques